# Unique php multidimensional array and sort by occurrence

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multiD array like:-

```
$a = array($arrayA,  $arrayB, $arrayA, $arrayC, $arrayC, $arrayA...........)
```

how can I get a resulting array which have distinct elements from this array and sorted with the more occurrence first like:-

```
array( $arrayA, $arrayB, $arrayC)
```

because array `$arrayA` was 3 times in first array so it comes first in resulting array.

I have tried :-

```
$newArray = array();
$count = count($a);
$i = 0;

foreach ($a as $el) {
if (!in_array($el, $newArray)) {
    $newArray[$i] = $el;
    $i++;
}else{
    $oldKey = array_search($el, $newArray);
    $newArray[$oldKey+$count] = $el;
    unset($newArray[$oldKey]);
}
}
krsort($newArray);
```

This is perfectly working but this is very lengthy process because my array has thousands of elements. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :-

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Comment: try to ask the effort first,then give the code. It's a code-editing platform not a code-giving platform

Comment: @Anant please try to answer if you can solve the problem.  You hvnt gave any solution instead of it you are finding excuses.i am new on stackoverflow thats why I hvnt posted my effort because it was not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Like @saravanan answer but result sorted:-

```
<?php

$input = [['b'],['a'],['b'],['c'],['a'],['a'],['b'],['a']];

$result = array_count_values( array_map("serialize", $input));
arsort($result,SORT_NUMERIC);
$result = array_map("unserialize",array_keys($result));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: try to ask the effort first,then give the code. It's a code-editing platform not a code-giving platform

Comment: @Anant i do not see your point, a prefectly valid question with a good answer, future readers will not care about OP's effort

Comment: @cske  thanks buddy but this will not work if we have two elements with same no of occurrence. Exe. If $arrayX and $arrayY both occurs 5 times than it will show only $arrayY.